# Is there any way to update data from a sql database from a api using android studio with java?

Tags: java, android, mysql, api

I have a sql database where i store products, and then i send it to a api, which my android application uses to parse their info and present it in a listview when pressing a button.

What i want to know is, can i change a sql database table from the android application using the API? If not, what are my best options to do so?

Comment: As you use a REST Api to get the data you can also UPDATE and DELETE

Comment: How can i do so? I didnt find anything online about it, and when i did, it was using PHP and not Java.

Comment: Searchengine shows for example https://phppot.com/php/php-mysql-rest-api-for-android/

Comment: I have coded my API using C#, but i cant find anyone using it, should i make a new one with PHP instead? Or does the android code apply to C# too?

Comment: The REST api is used to make it more secure, as you need for direct access deleiver your api with credentials **and** open it to the the internet, which is considered very dangerous. the php script on the mysql server side, inceases the security as you communicate over tcpip and html. And yes you must restructure your app for REST.

Comment: `I have coded my API using C#`, something like this https://github.com/esdanielgomez/ASP.NET_WebAPI/blob/master/Controllers/UserController.cs  ? So add endpoints to your API to do CRUD on the database and hit them from Android (or any http client).